# How does the splitting type of a tamely ramified prime $p$ determine the splitting type in its Galois closure?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Suppose $K/\mathbb{Q}$ is a non-Galois number field of degree $n$, and $p$ is a rational prime that ramifies tamely in $K$. We say $p$ is tamely ramified in $K$ if $(p,n) = 1$. If we know how $p$ ramifies in $K$, does that determine how $p$ ramifies in its Galois closure $\tilde{K}$? I received an affirmative answer in one of my previous post (and also saw another answer from a different post) that $e = \text{lcm}\{e_i\}$ and $f = \text{lcm}\{f_i\}$. But I'm not sure how one arrives at that answer and I'm trying to work it out for the case below right now.

My example:

I tried working out the case for $n=4$ for a non-Galois quartic field $K$ whose Galois closure has Galois group $S_4$. For one of the sub-cases, suppose $p\mathcal{O}_K = P^3_1P_2$ is the decomposition of $p$ in $\mathcal{O}_K$ and is tamely ramified. Here, we say $p$ has splitting type $(1^31)$ as the $P_1$ has ramification index 3 and inertia degree 1, and $P_2$ has ramification index 1 and inertia degree 1. I realize that the extension $\tilde{K}/K$ is Galois with Galois group $S_3$, and so it must follow the $efg$ theorem. It follows that every prime ideal of $\mathcal{O}_K$ must have splitting type $(111111), (222), (33), (1^31^3), (2^3), (1^21^21^2)$. For example, it is impossible for prime ideals in $\mathcal{O}_K$ to ramify with splitting type $(3^2)$ as that would imply that the decomposition group is $S_3$, with inertia group $C_2$. But we know $C_2$ is not a normal subgroup of $S_3$ and that is a contradiction.

Using similar logic, I deduce that $P_1$ cannot ramify in the Galois closure since ramification indices are multiplicative across tower of extensions, and that would imply $e = 6$ or $e =9$. But $S_4$ does not contain an element of order 6 nor 9. Similarly, it cannot ramify with splitting type $(33)$ as the decomposition group would have order 9, and $9 \nmid \mid S_4\mid$. So $P_1$ must have splitting type $(111111)$ or $(222)$. Likewise, we can deduce that $P_2$ must ramify with splitting type $(1^31^3)$ or $(2^3)$. But I am unsure how to show that it should be the former, and not the latter for both $P_1$ and $P_2$. I feel like I am missing a crucial piece to solving all the other cases and would appreciate any hints/tips!

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I’m not sure you’re using the right notion of tame ramification. If there’s one prime above $p$ with ramification index divisible by $p$, why should it be tame? At any rate: have you tried working with explicit examples, where the decomposition of $P_1,P_2$ can be known (with eg Sage)?

Comment: For $n=3$, here’s a counterexample to the “lcm of $f_i$” claim: let $p \equiv 2 \pmod{3}$ and consider $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{p})$. The factorization of $p$ in $K/\mathbb{Q}$ is $(1^3)$, but in the Galois closure it’s $(2^3)$…

Comment: @Aphelli Hi, thanks for the reply. I have checked with PARI-GP and you are absolutely right. It is a counter-example. My definition of tame ramification is also incorrect it seems. I have looked up the proper definition and fortunately, it does apply to the case I am working on. For the case non-Galois quartic field with Galois closure $S_4$, any prime $p>3$ is still tamely ramified. Does $e = \text{lcm}\{e_i\}$ still hold true in general though?